Is it possible to use Google Pay in a game app that isn’t listed on the Play Store
I'm developing a mobile game and I don't plan to list it on the Google Play Store. However, I want to integrate Google Pay for in-app purchases. Is this allowed? Are there any restrictions or policies for using Google Pay in apps that aren’t distributed via the Play Store?


This reddit seems to indicate that technically it's possible : https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/17y89go/is_it_possible_to_have_an_app_outside_playstore/  - From the Google Pay policies : https://pay.google.com/about/policy/ it doesn't seem to be forbidden.
